# React Native Android app crashes while launching

Tags: android, react-native, native-base

[image]

My app crashed while launching. It is working fine in ios.

Package.json is below

```
{
  "name": "Leave",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest",
    "postinstall": "remotedev-debugger --hostname localhost --port 5675 --injectserver"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "native-base": "2.1.1",
    "react": "16.0.0-alpha.6",
    "react-native": "0.43.4",
    "react-native-actionsheet": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-elements": "0.10.3",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.1.0-rc.1",
    "react-native-i18n": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-loading-spinner-overlay": "^0.4.4",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.15.2",
    "react-native-message-bar": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "4.2.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "4.0.0",
    "react-redux": "5.0.3",
    "redux": "3.6.0",
    "redux-thunk": "2.2.0",
    "superagent": "^3.5.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "19.0.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "1.9.1",
    "flow-bin": "0.42.0",
    "jest": "19.0.2",
    "react-native-dotenv": "0.0.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "15.4.2",
    "remote-redux-devtools": "^0.5.10",
    "remote-redux-devtools-on-debugger": "^0.7.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Logs from logcat is given below

```
com.facebook.react.bridge.UnexpectedNativeTypeException: TypeError: expected dynamic type `int64', but had type `null'
                                                                 at com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableNativeMap.getInt(Native Method)
                                                                 at com.facebook.react.devsupport.StackTraceHelper.convertJsStackTrace(StackTraceHelper.java:104)
                                                                 at com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSupportManagerImpl$3.run(DevSupportManagerImpl.java:290)
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Please help.

I have try this https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/5646
but it was not working for me

Comment: Check the output of `adb logcat`, there are usually some useful pointers there.

Comment: logcat logs are added

Comment: It looks like some native code is being called from JavaScript with the wrong parameter (namely `null` instead of a `Number`). You should check your code and then check if any of your dependencies is triggering the error.

Comment: issue is with react-native-maps not wrong parameter

Answer (score 3):

I found the problem the issue is with react-native-maps. Fix is given below

update

```
"react-native-maps": "^0.15.2"
```

to

```
"react-native-maps": "0.15.2".
```

Also I think "^" will cause problem in other dependencies in future. So I have removed them from my **Package.json**

Comment: btw, what does `^` mean in package.json?

Comment: @Felix `^` means it will update you to the next minor version automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, Nikhil's answer put me on the right track, unfortunately it was another dependency that was causing the crash.

It took me some time to pinpoint it, here is how I proceeded.

Step 1 : I removed every ^ before dependency's version number in package.json.

Step 2 : add ^ before **ONE** dependency's version number

Step 3 : remove dependency from node_modules and reinstall it (npm i)

Step 4 : restart package manager and restart application, if it starts without crashing, go to step 2

Optionnal step : Fix the dependency and send a merge request :)

Hope this helps.